# Increase size of syslogd messages

Tags: linux, syslog, syslog-ng

I am trying to send a script output to syslogd file. As the script output is large, its is split into 2-3 syslog messages, size of each message is 1024.

So, can I increase the size of the message? And what is the maximum size will I be able to increase?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

recent versions of syslog-ng use a 8192-byte limit to the maximal message size, so if your script does not break the lines, you shouldn't have any problems. For older versions, [increase the value of the log-msg-size() option in syslog-ng](https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/reference-options.html)