# How to increase the message size is being sent to rsyslog by syslog4j inside a java application

Tags: java, logging, syslog, rsyslog, syslog4j

I have long log messages to be passed through `rsyslog`. The logs are being generated via `syslogj` library that splits the logs into **1024** chars length chunks then sends them to `rsyslog` (based on what's noted [here](https://community.microfocus.com/t5/ArcSight-User-Discussions/Syslog-truncated-at-1024-bytes/m-p/1562059/highlight/true#M31797)) :

> There some applications that do *not* ignore the RFC tho, log4j 1.2.15 is one of them (and probably later versions too).  **If the size of the message >= 1024 bytes, log4j will divide it and send 2 messages regardless of MTU**.

AFAIK This has nothing to do with rsyslog, since we have already large logs from remote sources, and also setting `$MaxMessageSize 64k` in `/var/rsyslog.conf` didn't change anything.

How could we increase the message size in `syslog4j`? There's a constant in `org.productivity.java.syslog4j.SyslogConstants` class which denotes a **1024** size, but I'm not sure if it's related to my issue:

```
public static final int SYSLOG_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
```

Furthermore, didn't find any method for this job. (like the ones below)

```
SyslogIF syslogInstance;
syslogInstance = Syslog.getInstance("tcp");
syslogInstance.getConfig().setHost(host);
syslogInstance.getConfig().setPort(port);
```

P.s: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41596051/190929) apparently has a similar problem but neither mentioned it's via `syslog4j` nor got any answer.